# Change full url path with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change page url with .htaccess my url is 'page.com/web/' and I want to have just page.com. Could you give me htacces code. for example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?$1 [L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web?$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Is `/web/` a directory? Does `/web/` also have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ web/$1 [NC,L]
```